# connect to database from widget class

Tags: java, android, sqlite, class, android-widget

in widget Receiver class that extend *AppWidgetProvider* when i want to connect to database helper class for fetching some data by this statement i get some error:

```
public class wigetactivity extends AppWidgetProvider {

@Override
public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager,int[] appWidgetIds) {

    final DataBaseHelper myDbHelper = new DataBaseHelper(this);
         .
         .
         .
        }
```

i get this error: The constructor DataBaseHelper(wigetactivity) is undefined

my database helper class and constructor definition is:

```
public class DataBaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
            public DataBaseHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DB_NAME, null, 1);
    this.myContext = context;
}

 }
```

in a regular class that extends Activity i connect successfully to database, How i can fix that?

Comment: please post the whole stack trace and the code context when you create your helper, so we can see what `this` refers to

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `this` (which is not a `Context` in this case), use the provided `context`:

```
  final DataBaseHelper myDbHelper = new DataBaseHelper(context);
```

Comment: what is context in this case? how i can define it?

Comment: You're getting it as a parameter: `public void onUpdate(Context context, ...`